# How to get substring from line in bash or shell based on special character

Tags: bash, shell

I am reading file and iterating in bash, file contains multiple lines
sample one line is

`./ghgjjj1/kghgghh/ghghjjh/provFile.proeprties:prodVal=https://someabdcd.net:8080/someUri/someaction`

Can someone please suggest how to get the output as below.

`Val1=ghgjjj1 Val2=prodVal Val3=https://someabdcd.net:8080/someUri/someaction`

Tried many ways but no luck.

Comment: Are there any other examples or they all look exactly like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with [parameter expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

```
line='./ghgjjj1/kghgghh/ghghjjh/provFile.proeprties:prodVal=https://someabdcd.net:8080/someUri/someaction'

# remove shortest match at beginning (#) (./)
tmp=${line#./} 

# remove longest match "/*" at the end (%%) (/*)
val1=${tmp%%/*}

# remove shortest match at beginning (#) (*:)
tmp=${line#*:}

# etc.
val2=${tmp%%=*}
val3=${tmp#*=}
```

Comment: Can it possible to put this data in create excel and columns $val, $val2, $val3..
can you please suggest

Comment: answer gives an example on how to use parameter expansion, if answers the question please accept. Excel is another question.

Comment: Hey, Sry i am new to stackoverflow.

Comment: Answer absolutely correct and accepted..
can you please help to write that in excel... - Sreeni.

Comment: i mean another question should be asked

Comment: Yeah got it, created new, can you please help mate.. :)
https://stackoverflow.com/q/62697270/12951317